# Sorting a list with a checkbox column in android

Tags: android, sorting, listview, comparator

I have a listview in android that contains four columns in the row. It can be sorted by two columns (id, group) the other two are a color status value and a checkbox.  Currently the rows are being sorted using comparators for the id, group however when I called notify only these values are sorted the color and checkbox are not. Is there a way to sort the list based on the row?

Added the code for the id comparator:

```
public static class IDComparator implements Comparator<MyObject> {
        @Override
        public int compare(MyObject lhs, MyObject rhs) {
            if (lhs.getID() == null) {
                if (rhs.getID() == null) {
                    //equal
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    //lhs is <
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            if (rhs.getID() == null) {
                //lhs is >
                return 1;
            }
            //neither null
            if (lhs.getID() < rhs.getID()) {
                return -1;
            } else if (lhs.getID() > rhs.getID()) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

This method is called from here:

```
 Collections.sort(myList, IDComparator);
```

Comment: Put your code of comparators

Answer (score 1):

I am using Collection.sort for sorting like this in my project :

```
 Collections.sort(headerList, new Comparator<HeaderVO>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(HeaderVO e1, HeaderVO e2) {
              return Double.valueOf(e2.getPNo()).compareTo(Double.valueOf(e1.getPNo()));
        }
});
```